# layout_width attribute android

Tags: android-layout

Im getting the error "you must supply a layout_width attribute android" any suggestions?  I thought it was the xmlns line in the first row but still nothing.

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4" />


</GridLayout>
```

Comment: I think @martenson is right, please accept his answer, if it has solved you problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `wrap_content` instead of non-existent `wrap_parent`